# Trying to create a timer function by using millis() on an Arduino

Tags: c++, arduino

Im building a couple of interactions using Arduino for a school-project. One of the interactions is going to be knocking. I have a knocking pattern looks like this within the switch:

```
  long currentMillis = millis();

  knockValue = analogRead(soundSensor);

  if(numberOfKnocks < 3 && knockValue > quietKnock && knockValue < loudKnock) {
    if(checkForKnock(knockValue) == true) {
        previousMillis = currentMillis;
        checkTimer();
        numberOfKnocks++;
        Serial.println("Correct!");
        } else {
          numberOfKnocks = 0;
          Serial.println("Fail!");
          }
          delay(100);   
      } 

        if (numberOfKnocks == 3) {
          Serial.println("All well!");

            digitalWrite(LED_GREEN, HIGH);
            delay(200);
            digitalWrite(LED_GREEN, LOW);
            delay(200);
            digitalWrite(LED_GREEN, HIGH);
            delay(200);
            digitalWrite(LED_GREEN, LOW);
            numberOfKnocks = 0;
          }
```

The problem right now is that there is no time limit between the knockings. Ive been trying to use the millis() to create a timer that sets off with the first knock, and then resets the numberOfKnocks to 0 if all three knockings doesnt happen within 5 or so seconds.

The function i came up with looks something like this:

```
void checkTimer() {
  if (currentMillis - previousMillis >= interval) {
  digitalWrite(LED_RED, HIGH);
  delay(100);
  digitalWrite(LED_RED, LOW);
  Serial.println("HERE KNOCK SHOULD BE ZEROOOOO");
  numberOfKnocks = 0;
  }
```

I would really appreciate if someone here could help my clarify how this should look to function properly.

Sincerely //

Answer (score 0):

If you want to make sure that the last 3 knocks all occurred within the last 5 seconds (or x seconds), there is a specific trick you can use to accomplish this.

You keep a circular array of the last 3 knocks in memory. You use the modulus operator to assign values to it cyclically and you check the interval between the most recent and the farthest tracked knock by subtracting subsequent values in the array.

I altered your code a bit to demonstrate. Look for `last3KnockMillis[3]` and see how I use it:

```
//Solution:
long last3KnockMillis[3];
//***********

long knockValue = 0;
static int lastKnockIndex = 0;
long numberOfKnocks = 0;
long quietKnock = 500;
long loudKnock = 3000;

void setup() {
    //Other code...

    last3KnockMillis[0] = 0;
    last3KnockMillis[1] = 0;
    last3KnockMillis[2] = 0;
}

void loop() {
    //Other code...

    if (numberOfKnocks < 3 && knockValue > quietKnock&& knockValue < loudKnock) {
        if (checkForKnock(knockValue) == true) {
            lastKnockIndex = (lastKnockIndex + 1) % 3;
            last3KnockMillis[lastKnockIndex] = millis();
            checkTimer();
            numberOfKnocks++;


            //Other code...
        }
    }

    //Other code...
}

void checkTimer() {
    long longestInterval = abs(last3KnockMillis[lastKnockIndex] - last3KnockMillis[(lastKnockIndex + 1) % 3]);

    if (longestInterval > 5000) {
        numberOfKnocks = 0;
        last3KnockMillis[0] = 0;
        last3KnockMillis[1] = 0;
        last3KnockMillis[2] = 0;
        //ETC...
    }
}
```